# Calculation of current time in android

Tags: android, date, notifications

suppose I click start button and close the application but Notification is running. After five miutes I open notification then second activity opens and settext with 5 min.Again i close appliction.Then again I click on start button.suppose after 3 min i check notification it should open with 3 min not 8.but in my application it show 8 min

**1:Main ACtivity where notification is start**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
final Context context=this;
private EditText timerValue;
private static final int NOTIFY_ME_ID=1337;
Intent MyIntent;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    timerValue = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.timerValue111);

    startButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.startButton);
    x=timerValue.getText().toString();
    nman=(NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    startButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


        @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
        public void onClick(View view) {

            Long s1=(long) 0.0;
            String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss").format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
            //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,timeStamp,2000).show();

            Date interestingDate = new Date();
            s1= interestingDate.getTime();




            int seconds = (int) (s1/ 1000) % 60 ;
            int minutes = (int) ((s1 /(1000*60)) % 60);
            int hours   = (int) ((s1 /(1000*60*60)) % 24);


            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Time:"+hours+":"+minutes+":"+seconds,2000).show();

            NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);


            String MyText = "Reminder";
            Notification mNotification = new Notification(R.drawable.ic_launcher, MyText, System.currentTimeMillis() );

            //The three parameters are: 1. an icon, 2. a title, 3. time when the notification appears



            String MyNotificationTitle = "Medicine!";
            String MyNotificationText  = "Don't forget to take your medicine!";

            MyIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,SecondActivity.class);
            MyIntent.putExtra("s1", (long)s1);

            PendingIntent StartIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(),0,MyIntent,0);
            // x=timerValue.getText().toString();



            //A PendingIntent will be fired when the notification is clicked. The FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT flag cancels the pendingintent


            mNotification.setLatestEventInfo(getApplicationContext(), MyNotificationTitle, MyNotificationText, StartIntent);

            mNotification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
            notificationManager.notify(0,   mNotification);



        }
    });


}



}
```

2:Second Activity where total time is calculated

```
public class SecondActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    long p=(long) 0.0;
    long s=(long) 0.0;
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);
    TextView text1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.text1);

    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras(); 

    Date interestingDate = new Date();
     s= interestingDate.getTime();


    long x1=extras.getLong("s1");

     p=s-x1;

    int minutes = (int) ((p /(1000*60)) % 60);

    text1.setText(""+minutes);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.second, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

Comment: wat u are asking is not clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is happening maybe because you do not close the application, so the application goes in onPause state, and your second activity is not calling the onDestroy => when you enter again in the second activty, is called the onResume method, where you do not set the TextView text

Comment: suppose I click start button and close application.Notification is running after five miutes I open notification then second activity open and settext with 5 min.again i close appliction.then again I clcik on start button.suppose  after 3 min i check notification it should open with 3 min not 8.but in my application it show 8 min.OnDestroy not working bro.it show same as preveous

Comment: OK, i understood now.

Comment: Log the part after the `s1= interestingDate.getTime();` in the first activity and see if you get the correct date.

Comment: yes.. date gives correct time current system time....when i start application again it satrt from from next current time i think MainActivty is fine..there is problem in secondActivity..thank you for you help..if you exactly then please tell me.thanks in advance

Comment: It is weird, the only thing I can think of is that you are sending a past time through your notification in `MyIntent.putExtra("s1", (long)s1);`, that you do not send the new system time, but the old one. Try using `MyIntent.putExtra("s1",System.currentTimeMillis();`

Comment: nope its not working..anyway i will find solution and show here..thank you very much for your help

Comment: copy the code from `onCreate` to the `onResume` method of the SecondActivity and see if that works

Comment: second time when we open application and click on start button...click on notification it send previous time..myIntent.putExtra("s1",s1) this is where problem is occured..it does not send start time properly

Comment: as I said earlier.. that must be the problem... it seems like the notification is not done right, I did not work with notifications so I could not help you with that, sorry. Good Luck and when you resolved it please come back and say what was the problem because I am very curious :)

Comment: PendingIntent pendingIntent =PendingIntent.getActivity(context, (int)(Math.random() * 100),MyIntent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

Comment: Actually it does not update flag of pending event..we need to add update flag and random unique identifier for each intent as above i mention pending intent this is what we want to replaced preveous intent now code run perfect...thank you for your suggestion